# Check who has accessed my drive via a network C$ share in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, domain, shared-folders

Can you please advise if there is an option to check who has accessed my local C: drive in Windows over C$ network share 
(I know admins can do that)

My PC is in domain

Comment: Unless you are an Administrator, you do not have the necssary permissions, to determine this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see active files currently opened (which include over the share):

Computer Management > Share Folders > Open Files

You can see a live stream of file accesses with Sysinternals, ProcMon.exe

To see a historical log of anyone who has accessed that share over time, you'd need to have Security Policy updates and Auditing turned on.  Adding auditing to the C$ Share will cause events to be logged in the Event Log, Security log.

***If you're not already an Administrator on the system, you will not be able to do any of this.***

Edit:

In order to properly audit the activity on the filesystem, you need to turn on the auditing you actually want to see, in this case, Object Access in the Local Security Policy (gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policy > Audit Policy > Object Access (success|failure).

Next, you need to set up the Auditing itself.  Open Windows Explorer, right-click your 'C' drive.  Click the Security tab.  Click Advanced.  Click the Auditing tab.  Add users/group you coupled with the permissions you want audited in the Auditing tab.  Once done, all future accesses you requested to be audited, will appear in the Security log.

For the C drive, this will likely be massive.  Expect your security log to start rolling relatively quickly.  You may want to increase your security log capacity to address the new info.

Comment: Thanks will check that 
actually Im administrator. 
Re historical logs - wchich policy has to be turned on? 
Can I see events from past days or only after the time this policy was enabled?

Comment: See edited answer.